# text box with multiple bindings?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

Is there a way have a single textbox bind to two things. I want to have one binding set to "OneWay" and the Other set to "OneWayToSource". Basically I want to combine these two textboxes into one (and preferably with little to no code behind).

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ActionParameter.Value, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />

<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=StatusSignal.Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `MultiBinding` to set 2 or more `bindings` to your `TextBox`

Example:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
            <Binding Path="ActionParameter.Value" Mode="OneWayToSource" />
            <Binding Path="StatusSignal.Value" Mode="OneWay" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

But depending on what you need to do with the 2 properties you may need to use a `IMultiValueConverter` to process the properties.

Example:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <local:TextConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    </TextBox.Resources>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
            <Binding Path="ActionParameter.Value" Mode="OneWayToSource" />
            <Binding Path="StatusSignal.Value" Mode="OneWay" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```